# Perfomance of -webkit-keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations

I have the following CSS animation:

```
.already-visible {
  -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-transform: translateY(0);
  -moz-transform: translateX(0);
  -moz-animation: none;
}

.come-left-in {
    display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translateX(-1000px);
  -webkit-animation: come-in 1s ease-out forwards;
  -moz-transform: translateX(-1000px);
  -moz-animation: come-in 1s ease forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes come-left-in {
  to {  -webkit-transform: translateX(0);    
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes come-left-in {
  to {  -moz-transform: translateX(0);    
  }
}
```

I used it to show the title of each section in the home page as the user scroll down (using scrollspy from Bootstrap 3). But when I scroll while the animation is running, I notice a lack of performance, like a little "jump". Is there a way to avoid this? I am thinking about using left css property animation instead translate transform, but I prefer to consult first this issue.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use 3d transformations which are generally GPU accelerated (even if your transformation is 2d).

```
.already-visible {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation: none;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-animation: none;
}

.come-left-in {
    display: block;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0);
  -webkit-animation: come-in 1s ease-out forwards;
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-1000px, 0, 0);
  -moz-animation: come-in 1s ease forwards;
}


@-webkit-keyframes come-left-in {
  to {  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);    
  }
}
@-moz-keyframes come-left-in {
  to {  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);    
  }
}
```

Read more on [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/speed/html5/)
Also, [here](http://aerotwist.com/blog/on-translate3d-and-layer-creation-hacks/).

Comment: I have tried your solution but it stills "jumps" when I scroll while the animation is running.

Answer (score 0):

i dont know how webkit calculates transformations, but usually its done by multiplying matrices which can be very painful.

i would use `margin-left` though, instead of just `left`. 
`margin-left` would calculate the distance from the parent element, works for me all the time for keyframe animations.